# My function is able to remove just first element if x, recursion is not working

Tags: c++

The code is to replace x from a string . But recursion is not working .

I have provided the solution below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<cstring>
using namespace std;
string remove_x(string s)
{
    int n=s.length();
    if(n==0)
    {
        return "not found";
    }
    if(s[0]=='x')
    {
        s.erase(s.begin());
        remove_x(s);
    }
    else
    {
        remove_x(s.substr(1,n));
    }
    return s;
}

int main() {
  string str;
  cin>>str;
  str=remove_x(str);
  cout<<str;
}
```

i expect that my function removes all x in the string.

Comment: You're copying the string into each function call, so modifying it has no effect. And you ignore return value of all your recursive calls.

Comment: Voting to close as a typo.  You forgot to pass by reference.  `string remove_x(string s)` -> `string remove_x(string& s)`

Comment: @NathanOliver That is not the only issue though.

Comment: Changing to pass-by-reference won't work on it's own since `remove_x(s.substr(1,n));` will no longer compile.

Comment: Reasonably well posed question, but you could have solved this yourself by adding a few `cout << s;`s  at strategic points or stepping through the code with a debugger.

Answer (score 2):

The issue here is that you are not passing your string by reference, you are passing it by value (the function gets a copy of it, not the actual version you are working with). I would recommend passing a reference to s along with an integer that represents where you are in the string.

Comment: Don't pass a string _and_ a pointer to somewhere in that string; that's poor design. Either pass a string and an index, or pass a pointer (and assume null-termination), or pass an iterator range.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I was not suggesting they pass the string AND a pointer, I was suggesting they pass a string pointer and an integer that lets them know how far through the string they are.

Comment: Cool (yeah I misread that soz); in that case a reference would be preferable to the pointer, but otherwise nice

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit You're right, a reference would be better. I've been doing lots of C lately, my bad.

Answer (score 2):

If you pass a reference to `s` then you need a position in the string to keep track of. There's also no need to return the string in that case.

```
void remove_x_inplace(string& s, size_t i) {
  if (i >= s.size()) return;
  if (s[i] == 'x')
    s.erase(s.begin() + i);
  remove_x_inplace(s, i + 1);
}

void remove_x_inplace(string& s) { remove_x_inplace(s, 0); }
```

If you would like to return the string, then the recursive strategy is to simply choose to append the current character with the rest of the modified string iff the current character is not an `x`:

```
string remove_x(string s) {
  if (s.empty()) return s;
  string rest = remove_x(s.substr(1));
  return s[0] == 'x' ? rest : s[0] + rest;
}
```